# How to interpret Sufyan a-Thawri's statement on permission in fatwas?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, fatwa

[Ibn 'Abd al-Barr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_%27Abd_al-Barr) quoted in his Jami' bayan al-'Ilm wa fadlih [جامع بيان العلم وفضله](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=349041&bk_no=696&startno=72)  a statement of imam [Sufyan a-Thawri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufyan_al-Thawri) سفيان بن سعيد الثوري‎ with a -apparently- conected narrator chain saying -as if it was a hadith-:
<sub>In the following I will translate from Arabic as this is my own translation take it carefully -corrections/inputs are welcome-</sub>

> " إِنَّمَا  الْعِلْمُ عِنْدَنَا الرُّخْصَةُ مِنْ ثِقَةٍ ، فَأَمَّا التَّشْدِيدُ فَيُحْسِنُهُ كُلُّ أَحَدٍ ".
>   (Real) Knowledge with us (in our opinion) is a permission from a trustworthy person, while rigour can be made (declared) by anybody

This statement is about fatwa as it was quoted in a chapter about fiqh and its knowledge base.

This statement is also often used and quoted in books of sheikh [Yusuf al-Qaradawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yusuf_al-Qaradawi) who consider seeking easier "verdicts" as essential.

What are the limits of such permissions or easier verdicts?

And how is this statement interpreted and when does it apply?